# In an interfaith marriage, would the non-Muslim partner be prohibited from celebrating e.g. Easter, Christmas?

Tags: interfaith, holidays, celebration

As Muslims we do not celebrate holidays like Easter or Christmas.  However if you were involved in an interfaith marriage (with someone from the "people of the book"), would the other person be prohibited from celebrating such holidays? Or are they allowed to celebrate as long as you (as a Muslim) do not, but just wish them "well" out of respect and politeness?

Where does Islam stand on this?

Comment: If you'll check fatwa sites like islamqa (especially) they will tell you that you as a (Muslim) husband should lead your household including prohibiting your (non-Muslim) wife to do any kind of shirk etc. honestly I can't see how this goes ahead with the teachings of Islam. In first place a working relationship should be one in which people communicate with each other and respect each other and this certainly is not against a shari'a in which Allah always use kind and soft words like "If you fear (that)..." when talking about matters between spouses!